# SpringBoot unable to read META-INF/spring.tld

Tags: spring-boot

Anyone encounter this in springboot sample app ?

I am using embedded tomcat in SpringBoot and hit the error below when going to the initial page.

Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [/WEB-INF/jsp/welcome.jsp (line: 3, column: 68) Unable to read TLD "META-INF/spring.tld" from JAR file "jar:file:/Users/chyn/dev/poc/poc-springbootwebjsp/target/poc-springbootwebjsp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/spring-webmvc-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar": java.io.IOException: Unable to open root Jar file 'jar:file:/Users/chyn/dev/poc/poc-springbootwebjsp/target/poc-springbootwebjsp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar'] with root cause

Comment: I copy the tld in local and change the jsp to refer it from local and it works. Thanks

Comment: I have the same problem, interesting enough, if I run the application using mvn spring-boot:run, this error doesn't occur. I'll try copying the files locally.